# How to choose the data structure for finding sentences with only known words

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I am working on a language learning program. The program tracks the words it thinks a user knows, and I want to add a feature where I show the user sentences that they should be able to read.

I have a large data set of tokenized sentences, but I'm struggling to come up with the right data structure to make filtering this list fast enough. My first pass was just iterating through it all every time a user learns a new word, but this is proving to be too slow, especially since a user often learns several words during a session. Furthermore, the list of sentences changes over time, either as the user adds sentences of their own or my global database of sentences has sentences added/removed/updated.

What is a good data structure for making this search fast while supporting the dynamic nature of the data? That is, given the set of words the user knows, and a whole ton of tokenized and perhaps further pre-processed sentences, I want to quickly find the sentences that the user should be able to read all of the words in.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of problem, the best way to go is to use a tree. I would recommend you to take a look to [Tries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) or to [Radix trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree). They allow reducing the search to a logarithmic time.

[image: Radix Tree vs Trie]

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer (and picture)! I'm not sure that I understand though - what are you suggesting building the tree from? The sentence database? And how are could I use that tree for sentences the user knows?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a tree of letters. A node would consist of the following members:

- the letter
- whether it is the end of a word

For example, on root level you would have a node 'a' which is a word of its own. One of its children would be 's', which is a word of its own as well, because reading it together with its parent you get 'as' and so on. Finding a word in this tree would take maximum 26 + length-of-the-word - 1.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding what you are saying, but the problem is different than this I think - I know all of the words the user knows, and the words in a given sentence. Finding whether the user knows all of the words in a given sentence is fast - it's just a set intersection (user_words.intersect(sentence_words) should be sentence_words - logarithmic time). The challenge I'm facing is that doing this for all of the tens of thousands of sentences is too slow.

Comment: @mindvirus doing a search for tens of thousands of sentences is basically the repetition of such a search. If your search is slower than necessary, it might not be felt upon the first search that you do, but adds up. If there are lots of words the user already knows, then searching them lineary is slow. It might be felt only in large stress tests as you have described, but that's a culprit. Consider the case when something takes 50 milliseconds instead of 5. As a human you will not feel it, but if you repeat it many times, you will wait for 10 hours instead of one.